# simplest way to count number of ones in an array in R

Tags: r

Is there a function which I can use to count the number of ones in an array in R?
I was looking for something which would save me the overhead of

```
count = 0;
myarray = c(1,1,0,1,0)  
for(i in 1:length(myarray))
{
 if(myarray[i] == 1)
 {
  count = count+1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is binary,

```
 sum(!!myarray) 
 #[1] 3
```

Or

```
 sum(myarray) #based on comments from @thelatemail
```

If not binary,

```
sum(myarray==1)
```

Comment: !!? Can't those be left out?

Comment: @mdsumner I used it to save a single character :-)

Comment: While `!!` works, it is essentially `sum(as.logical(myarray))` I can only imagine the potential debugging nightmare of using `!!` in combination with other code. Also, if it is just binary, `sum(myarray)` will give the same answer anyway.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, you are right. Thanks for the `sum(myarray)`.  Ananda Mahto already posted that the `as.logical`, so I would leave this as it is.

Comment: Whoops, hadn't scrolled down to @AnandaMahto's answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

There is also, of course, `table` or `tabulate`:

```
myarray = c(1,1,0,1,0)
table(myarray)
# myarray
# 0 1 
# 2 3 
tabulate(myarray)
# [1] 3
```

Also, I would prefer `sum(as.logical(myarray))` to double-negation with `!!` as @akrun used in his answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ananda Mahto ,I was able to extract ones' count using table(myarray)[1]

Comment: @IAMTubby, you would need something more like `table(myarray)[which(sort(unique(myarray)) == 1)]`.